# Unable to proxy authentication credentials in KDE

Tags: kde, proxy

I want to configure proxy authentication in KDE. in proxy setting there are two choices available: Prompt as needed and Username/Password. but last one is disabled...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a long standing bug in KDE

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=232626

The work around is to set a proxy manually, in ~/.bashrc

```
export http_proxy=http://<username>:<password>@<proxyIP>:<port>
```

You then have to use the `-E` with sudo

```
sudo -E apt-get update
```